# Application installed using NSIS should accessed by all users

Tags: nsis, multi-user

I have my application uses Sql server database. I have created installer installs sql server and application and also created database on that server. 
I need to do 
on one system multiple users should access same application by different logins.
how to do that?
sql server also installed for all users.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [AccessControl plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/AccessControl_plug-in) to grant access:

```
AccessControl::GrantOnFile "$instdir\database.db" "(S-1-5-32-545)" "GenericRead + GenericWrite" ; S-1-5-32-545 is BUILTIN\Users. Access rights could also be FullAccess etc
```